# Where to configure syndaemon settings?

Tags: 12.04, touchpad

Where do I configure syndaemon default parameters?

By default it is called with

 `-i 2.0 -K -R -t`

.
I have a script that re-runs it with parameters that I need, but how do I do this properly?

I am on ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dash -> Startup Applications

[image]

- Add
- Give it a name and put the command in for the script you need:

[image]

Reason for this ... there is not config file and those settings are hard coded.

Comment: Yes, that's what I do, just running the script from .bash_profile. I was hoping that there is any way to configure it. Thanks anyway

Comment: nope sorry. someone believes it is best to hard code something like that :)

Comment: If I do this, two `syndaemon` processes end up getting started.

Comment: Thank you for this answer ! I tried and failed with other solutions to this problem, this one solves it :D

Answer (score 4):

As Rinzwind already pointed out, these settings are hardcoded in unity-settings-daemon:

https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/vivid/unity-settings-daemon/vivid/view/head:/plugins/mouse/gsd-mouse-manager.c

As a workaround, rename syndaemon to syndaemon.orig

```
mv /usr/bin/syndaemon /usr/bin/syndaemon.orig
```

and create a script syndaemon that just calls the original binary with the correct parameters:

```
cat << EOF > /usr/bin/syndaemon
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/syndaemon.orig -K -R -i0.5
EOF
```

Make it executable with

```
chmod +x /usr/bin/syndaemon
```

Comment: This is kind of wonky, but it works and ensures only one `syndaemon` process is started at launch.

Answer (score 0):

For those using Xubuntu:

http://www.computercorrect.com/2012/operating-systems/linux/xubuntu/configure-disable-touchpad-while-typing-delay/

I've found that making it half a second delay works well for me. The command you need to run at auto start is

```
syndaemon -i .5 -K -t -R -d
```